# como guardar datos de un array en mi bd? laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

hola comunidad buenas resulta que debo guardar los datos de un array en mi bd pero me salta este error[image: error]

y cuando quito los corchetes si me deja guardar pero un unico dato tengo un script que me permite agregar una fila pero ya se me daña y sale el error
mi codigo es este

```
<form action="{{ url('invoices') }}" method="POST" class="form-group">
@csrf



<div class="row">



<div class="container">

<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center"> # </th>
          <th class="text-center"> Product </th>
          <th class="text-center"> Qty </th>
          <th class="text-center"> Dto </th>
          <th class="text-center"> Price </th>
          <th class="text-center"> Total </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id='addr0'>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
          <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='Enter Qty' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0"/></td>
          <td><input type="number" name='dto[]' placeholder='Enter Dto' class="form-control dto" step="0" min="0"/></td>
          <td><input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='Enter Unit Price' class="form-control price" step="0.00" min="0"/></td>
          <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='addr1'></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


              </form>
```

y este es el controlador y se que aca debo de convertir en string los datos que debo envia a mi bd pero no se como

```
 public function index()
    {
         
        // $rows= Aircraft::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with('customer')->get();
        $rows = Invoices::latest()->get();
       // $rowss = InvoiceTemp::latest()->get();
        return view('invoices.invoices', compact('rows'));
    }
```

lo que me pasa al pulsar para agregar otra fila me guarda el primer dato y me salta de una como si hubiera presionado guardar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando le doy a add row me manda el error es como si al addionar me enviara de una a la bd y me salta el error

estoy ahora json_encode pero me salta ya otro error :(

```
public function index()
    {
         
        // $rows= Aircraft::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with('customer')->get();
     $rows =Invoices::latest()->get();
     
        //$string= serialize($rows);
       // $rowss = InvoiceTemp::latest()->get();
      
        return view('invoices.invoices', compact('$rows'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('invoices.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       // dd($request->all());
        $data =array( $request->all());
        $exampleEncoded = json_encode($data);
        //$string= serialize($data);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO synercarft (billed,shipped,ordern,date,product,qty,dto,price,total,sub_total,tax,tax_mount,total_amount,textarea) VALUES ('$exampleEncoded')";
        Invoices::create( $data );
        return redirect('invoices');
    }
```

mi ruta va asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahora me salta esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres guardar en BD? Una fila por cada fila que tienes en el html?

Comment: hola buena tarde  esta parte <tr id='addr1'></tr>
 me agrega otra fila pero cuando presiono eso me sale el error de la foto

Comment: Ya debugeaste con dd() para ver que datos se agregan y como se agregan? Porque el atributo `name='addr0'` no es un array[] sino un string. y es por eso que falla.

Comment: ya agregue mas info de lo que me aparece gracias

Comment: Para tu último comentario "cuando le doy a add row me manda el error es como si al addionar me enviara de una a la bd y me salta el error" posiblimente sea algo del javascript, tendrías que poner un `preventDefault()` para que el formulario no se envíe al presionar el botón.

Comment: hola ya solucione lo del boton pero igual me sogue apareciendo el error de array @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: ¿Cuál es el método que usas para guardar? El que veo en la pregunta es el `index`, pero es sólo para obtener. ¿Podrías agregarlo a la pregunta?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ hola ya lo agregue esoy ahora tratando con el json pero ahora no se me sale error en la ruta y no se que es